# Redraw view with intervals from thread

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I need animate menu in custom view. It must be redrawed with intervals some times(about 10), but it redraws after thread stopped.

```
public void menuShift() {
    Runnable runnable  = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (TablesActivity.this.view.menuShifting) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100) ;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                TablesActivity.this.view.timerRefresh() ;
                TablesActivity.this.view.postInvalidate() ;
            }
        }
    } ;
    this.menuShiftThread = new Thread(runnable) ;
    this.menuShiftThread.run() ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.menuShiftThread.run(); is the problem, you need

```
this.menuShiftThread.start()
```

to actualy start a new thread.